# Automatically save attachments from mail on a network drive

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

Every morning I receive an automatically generated e-mail from a server, it includes a spreadsheet attachment. 
I made a rule in outlook that captures these emails. Now, I would like to make a macro to rename the attached file (. Xls) to =today() and saves it in a folder on a network drive. This macro must run every weekday at 8:00.
I've made a lot of VBA in Excel, but have no experience in outlook.
Might this be possible? And does anyone know how to do it?

Kind regards
Staal

Comment: How are you going to schedule the macro?

Comment: I would like to macro run automatically on weekday No 2,3,4,5 and 6 controlled by an if statement with a ontime time value ("08:00:00") How I made several macros in excel, but I know not whether it is possible in outlook?

Comment: It is possible, but something has to call your "if" statement.

Comment: I do not know if this is what you mean? But can you put a Private Sub In This Outlook Session There as follows:
Private Sub Workbook_Open ()
x = Weekday (Date)
If x = 2 Then
Application.OnTime TimeValue ("08:00:00"), "name of the sub"
End If
End Sub
It should then call the second macro that is in a module. If Outlook is open.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no OnTime method in Outlook. This is why I asked you about scheduling the macro =) You can try to workaround this by using wrapper tasks with reminders or something like that... But I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: Here is [additional code](http://www.pixelchef.net/content/rule-autosave-attachment-outlook) if your use case is slightly different when saving attachments in Outlook.

Comment: Why do you have requirement to run during weekday at 8:00am? You may have to use something outside of Outlook. Perhaps a scheduled task on a server that can pull e-mail from a specific mailbox. I think using Outlook is a poor solution for your specific requirements as it requires the Outlook client to be running for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Why delay the save until 8:00?

In the rule that "captures these emails" save with "run a script".

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String

saveFolder = "D:\temp"  ' change to your path

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xls"
Next

End Sub
```

---

Edit based on comment:

Not sure you would want to do this inside saveAttachtoDisk but to manipulate the Workbook once it is saved, there is Excel.

Try GetObject, if there is an error then use CreateObject("Excel.Application")
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288902

Then something like this, or whatever way works for you since you know Excel VBA.

Workbooks.Open(name of file)

Worksheets(1).Name = "Sheet 1"

---

Edit 2 based on comment:

You have to pass a parameter.

Open a mailitem then F8 here.

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk_test
Dim currItem as mailitem
set curritem = activeinspector.currentitem
saveAttachtoDisk curritem
set currItem = nothing
end sub
```

Comment: Invalid script found. Your script saves ALL attachments for a given message to one .xls file overwriting one by one. Moreover, you have no way to run it against selected messages. The best result you can get with this script + rule is to save last attachment in the selected folder to a file.

Comment: @thims True if there were more than the single attachment in the mail. "it includes a spreadsheet attachment."

Comment: Thank you, the run a script rule with the assigned macro run perfectly :-). However, I am now i see an unforeseen problem. The sheet my excel file contains also changes name, can I rename this in the same macro? So that it will always be called the same (possibly Sheet1)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to see if I can´t get it to work in this macro. However, I must have pressed the wrong button? because suddenly I can´t steppe me through macro with F8, anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The reason I commented the question is that there is no adequate way to achieve the desired result just by using Outlook VBA. You'll need to find some third-party solution. I personally can recommend the product of my company: [ReliefJet Essentials for Outlook Professional Edition](http://www.reliefjet.com/Product/Features/CommandLine). It provides the command line that can be utilized to schedule the **Save Attachments** utility using Windows Task Scheduler. While you'll *not* be able to rename the attachment itself, *it is possible* to create a folder named with any date-time pattern you can imagine for you attachment(s). The only drawback: you have to pay for it.